# Linq To Sql Inserting record with new associated record

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I have two tables:

```
[Table(Name="Booking")]
public class Booking
{
    private EntityRef<Transaction> _transaction;

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)] 
    public int ID;

    [Column] public int Quantity;
    [Column] public int EventID;
    [Column] public int TransactionID;

   [Association(Strorage = "_transaction", ThisKey = "TransactionID", OtherKey = "ID")]
    public Transaction Transaction
    {
        get { return _transaction.Entity; }
        set { _transaction.Entity = value; }
    }
}

[Table(Name="Transaction")]
public class Transaction
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID;

    [Column] public decimal Amount;
    [Column] public DateTime DatePaid;

}
```

I want to do the following:

```
Booking booking = new Booking
{
    /* set data */
    Transaction = new Transaction
       {
           Amount = 200,
           DatePaid = DateTime.Now
       }
}
db.Bookings.InsertOnSubmit(booking);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

But it doesn't insert transaction and flags a foreign key constraint error.

Is there any way I can add transaction with the booking at the same time without calling db.SubmitChanges() twice to get the TransactionID?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var booking = new Booking();
booking.Transaction.Add(new Transaction { Amount = 200, DatePaid = DateTime.Now });
db.Bookings.InsertOnSubmit(booking);
db.SubmitChanges()
```